# Перенос данных при репликации MySQL

Tags: mysql, репликация

Не могу до конца понять, что вообще значит термин "репликация" в рамках MySQL.

[На Хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/56702/) я встретила следующее описание процесса репликации:

> Изменения данных, происходящие на мастере, повторяются на репликах (но
> не наоборот). Поэтому запросы на изменение данных (INSERT, UPDATE,
> DELETE и т. д.) выполняются только на мастере, а запросы на чтение
> данных (проще говоря, SELECT) могут выполняться как на репликах, так и
> на мастере.
>
> ...
>
> Важно понимать, что при репликации передаются не сами измененные
> данные, а только запросы, вызывающие изменения.

Получается, что если на реплике изначально пустая база данных, то в неё будут добавляться только те данные, которые добавляются на мастер только после включения репликации? Т.е., те данные, которые были добавлены на мастер до репликации, на реплику не попадут?

С другой стороны, много где говорится, что репликация - это практически то же, что и синхронизация. А это как я понимаю, приведение баз данных к одному виду...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изначально на репликах находится копия мастера. Если все-таки вы настроите репликацию на пустую базу, то довольно быстро репликация будет сломана, так как не будут обнаружены нужные данные для выполнения запросов из бин-логов. Настройка реплики предполагает, что вы не просто копируете данные с мастера, но и очень точно выставляете координаты в бин-логах, начиная с которых начинаются выполняться новые команды.

> Т.е., те данные, которые были добавлены на мастер до репликации, на
>   реплику не попадут?

Сама процедура настройки репликации предполагает, что вы сначала воссоздаете копию мастера. Однако, если вам удастся этого избежать и не разломать в дальнейшем репликацию, да, они на реплику не попадут.

Answer (score 1):

Давайте разберем вообще, что такое репликация в MYSQL:

**Репликация** – есть ни что иное как “**синхронизация**” двух и/или более баз данных на различных серверах MySQL.

**Все запросы обновления базы всегда идут на головной сервер**. После мутирующей операции на головном сервере, он помещает об этом информацию в отдельный файл, откуда и берут всю информацию подчинённые сервера и добавляют к себе эти данные, как бы синхронизируясь до текущего состояния мастера.

Представим ситуацию, что у нас есть сервер, который имеет очень важные данные, например база данных банка. В один момент, мы можем представить, что сервер сгорит или попадет в какую-то ситуацию, когда его даже не спасет правильно настроенная репликация между дисками, а данные в любую секунду времени нам очень важны иначе мы теряем очень много денег, утренний бекап нам совсем не интересен, когда сервер сгорел вечером.

Нас спасет **репликация данных** с нулевым отставанием, мы создаем второй сервер, делаем на него копию текущей базы и догоняем ее запросами в автоматическом режиме до текущего состояния мастера. Главный сервер будем называть мастером, а зависимые — репликами (слейвами). Такое отношение называется master-slave, когда запись выполняется только на master, а чтение можно производить с мастера или слейва.

Теперь у нас есть слейв, и мы можем спокойно с него делать mysqldump не останавливая базу на технические работы (если она большая), можем выполнять тяжелые запросы на чтение, которые не помешают работе основной базы и если у нас откажет основной сервер, то мы можем быстро сделать реплику мастером и получаем минимальное время простоя.

Мы также можем настроить **отложенную репликацию** на другой сервер, например с заданным отставанием на 1 час, тогда не встретим проблем, что какой-то Вася, имеющий полный доступ к базе вместо UPDATE WHERE с обновлением 3 строк, написал просто UPDATE, где обновил всю таблицу.